# Contact Form 7 - process form using a PHP script, instead of mailing

Tags: uploads, plugin-contact-form-7

I want to use a form from the `Contact Form 7` plugin to allow the users to upload a document to my website. The problem is that I'd like to manage those uploads from WordPress instead of receiving them in my E-Mail.

Is there a way of redirecting the output of those forms to a PHP script, or something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook CF7 provides.

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else_with_the_data");
function wpcf7_do_something_else_with_the_data(&$wpcf7_data)
{

    // Everything you should need is in this variable
    var_dump($wpcf7_data);

    // I can skip sending the mail if I want to...
    $wpcf7_data->skip_mail = true;

}
```

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using var_dump here is not a good idea because you will write the output to the buffer and break the form submission. Use error_log wordpress functions with print_r or var_dump with the following code instead :

```
ob_start();                      // start buffer capture
var_dump($wpcf7_data);           // dump the values
$contents = ob_get_contents();   // put the buffer into a variable
ob_end_clean();                  // end capture
error_log($contents);            // Write to wp-content/debug.log (enable debug mode to see it).
```