# Display Image Upload from Contact Form 7 on Redirect Page

Tags: uploads, redirect, plugin-contact-form-7

How would I show an image upload, a photo of someone, in the Thank You page. It's for a competition.

NB: The user uploads an image and then that image is shown on the thank you page.

- I need to access the form data array
- find the file uploaded already
- and display this in an img tag on the thank you page
- I already have the redirect in place

I'm not very good at all with PHP, but I feel like I've been skirting the solution I just can't see it.

This [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44623/contact-form-7-process-form-using-a-php-script-instead-of-mailing) shows the possibility of using the data from the form but how would I extract the file variable and then use that to show it on the next page.

It would need to be a method that can handle numerous people using the form possibly at the same time. There are likely to be hundreds of entries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far and the results, along with the redirect you already have in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the [Contact Form DB plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/).

1. I used their [HTML shortcode](http://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=284) [cfdb-html] to call the img url saved to the wordpress database
2. Then I limited it to the most recent row (using the documentation available on their site) to make sure only the image was shown.
3. Some basic CSS finished it off.

Answer (score -1):

I think your question needs a bit more details but you should be able to [redirect users who submit the first CF7 form](http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/) to a Thank You page which simply has another CF7 form on it with an image upload field.

Comment: I have added more detail I hope that helps. What I need to do is take the uploaded photo of the user and show it to them on the Thank You page. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I managed to solve it myself and used the method below.